# Equivalence between function of random variables and random function of random variables

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, function, measure-theory

All the random variables in what follows are defined on the same probability space $(S, \mathcal{A}, P)$.

Let $W, Z, Q$ be Borel measurable random variables on $[0,1]$.

---

Assume

(*) $X|W, Z, Q \sim Be(t(W, Z, Q))$, where $Be$ denotes Bernoulli distribution, and  $t:[0,1]^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a Borel measurable function.

Define a random variable $V: S\rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is the space of all Borel measurable functions from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$, such that $\forall s \in S$, $V(s)(a,b)\equiv  t(W(s), a,b)$ $\forall (a,b)\in [0,1]^2$.

**Question 1:** is it true that (*) implies

(**) $X|V, Z, Q\sim Be(V(Z,Q))$
?

**Question 2:** is it obvious or am I using some more subtle properties on cardinalities or similar?

**Question 3:** is it true that $V$ takes value in $\mathcal{V}$ (*Borel* measurable maps) because the map $t:[0,1]^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ is assumed to be Borel measurable?

---

Suppose that now I want to go the other way around. 
Assume

(***) 
$X|V, Z, Q\sim Be(V(Z,Q))$

with $V: S\rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is the space of all Borel measurable functions from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$.

Consider a random variable $W$ taking value on $[0,1]$ and define a map $t:[0,1]^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\forall s\in S$, $t(W(s), a,b)\equiv V(s)(a,b)$ $\forall (a,b)\in [0,1]^2$.

**Question 4:** is it true that (***) implies

(****) $X|W, Z, Q\sim Be(t(W,Z,Q))$
?

**Question 5:** is it obvious or am I using some more subtle properties on cardinalities or similar?

**Question 6:** where does Borel measurability of $t$ come from?

Comment: Any direction or hint would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{V}$, necessary to define $P(V \in B)$ where $B$ any events of this $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I am not sure about it... do you have directions for that? Thank you

Comment: You may have more answers by reformulating the question as a pure measure theory one and posting it on math.stackexchange